# jQuery - Number Validation - Not a Valid Number

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin, jquery-form-validator, formvalidation.io

I'm using formvalidation.io (an extension of jQuery form validation) to validate my form and am having trouble with fields that have the type 'number'.

I want to use the type so that the number keys are presented to the user on mobile devices.

The validation on the field is very simple:

```
depth: {
    validators: {
    notEmpty: {
        message: 'You must enter the depth of the excavation.'
}
```

However it's the default validation of the number type field that causes the problem. The field will accept:
1.00, 1, 2.00 etc.

But will not accept any decimals:
0.50, 1.20, 2.30 etc.

The default validation "Please enter a valid number" is called

Comment: Have you thought of using regex to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the default HTML5 validation `type="number"` doesnt allow decimals without a [`step`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-step) specified.

From the FormValidation.io Docs:-

> When setting options via HTML attributes, remember to enable the
>   validator by setting data-fv-numeric="true".
>
> You don't need to do that when
>
> i) using HTML 5 type="number" attribute
>
> ii) and the **step**
>   attribute must be specified which its value is not an integer

Try this:-

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```